# Orchard CMS : how do I overload DriverResult display to be @model and support binding?

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

ARG! I am beating my head here for like 18 hrs over last 2 days, been like trying to run in a 4' pool of stucky mud...  I am sooooo close and fear I am going to have to walk in Monday with a NON result for all my labor...

Big picture:

I have a widget that needs to consider the users zipcode, and based on this provide a list of events within their area.

If the GeoIp lookup is off, or the users is interested in looking else where they can reach up and change the ZipCode to any of their choosing and "postback", having the modules redraw.

I have the widgets looking up from another DB and rendering just fine as a widget.

I have it all working just as I want..  I "think" what I want is for the

```
    protected override DriverResult Display(
        SeminarPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
```

to be something I can bind to in the .cshtml

```
@model CustomPart
```

but no matter what I do I get ->

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'IShapeProxyabb0e4251c0b4c71bfe70f2ec47bfca4', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type 'Blah.Blah.MoreBlah.CustomPart'.

If I can get all of this happy, I "THINK" I would be able to do something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedZipCode)
```

And ultimately then the model would refresh its result set, changing the `List<CustomData>` in the model and redrawing the list...  ???

---

The DANGDED editor part exposes GET and POST `DriverResult` Editor and seems to do what I had hoped I could do here...   anyone, ideas?

PPPPPPLLLLLLEEEEEASSE Roger....  much thanks in advance, -James et 10-Geek dot com...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `@model CustomPart` with `@model dynamic`. The Model passed to the view has been proxied by Orchard to allow it to do some stuff, and the proxied object is `dynamic`, NOT an instance of `CustomPart`.

This only applies to views displayed via the `Display(...)` method. In the view used for your `Editor(CustomPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)` method, you should use `@model CustomPart`.

Comment: But I really do want the static model, Thanks to Piedone from other forum I was able to actually bind to the model I wanted by doing the following. 


protected override DriverResult Display( MYCustomPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) { return ContentShape("Parts_Seminar", () => shapeHelper.DisplayTemplate( TemplateName: "Parts/MYCustom", Model: MYCustomService.GetMYCustomData(part), Prefix: Prefix));

Comment: Glad you found a solution :) Either will work, Piedone's approach is just more explicit. Just out of interest, why do you specifically need the CustomPart (and not it's Proxy)? I've never used DisplayTemplate() directly before, I've gotten around needing an explicitly-typed reference by just casting it in the view (i.e. `@{ var part = (CustomPart)Model; }` or something similar).